# Sqoop options to load a LOB column from rdbms to Hive

Tags: sqoop

I was trying to load LOB column (VARCHAR(28000)) from DB2 database to hive, I am using below sqoop options, but not getting success.
1.

```
--table
schema.tbl_name
        -m
        1
        --fetch-size
        1000

--map-column-java
                HVBA02_PRT_LIST_X=BINARY
                --map-column-hive
                HVBA02_PRT_LIST_X=BINARY
2. 
--table
schema.tbl_name
        -m
        1
        --fetch-size
        1000
--map-column-java
                col_name=String
                --map-column-hive
                col_name=String
```